# How to install monodevelop on kali offline?

Tags: kali-linux, mono

I have a kali VM on `virtualBox`.

I can transfer files to this VM but it doesn't have Internet connection.

How can I install `monodevelop`?

Comment: why even try to use kali as a general purpose or development system? it's not intended for that, it's a specialised penetration testing distribution (and, unfortunately, a script-kiddie fantasy OS for 12 year old w4nn4-b3 1337 hax0rs).   If you want a linux system to develop mono/.NET applications on then use a general purpose distribution.

Comment: @cas i know what yo say
but on kaly there are lot of package that i need .
do you have any idea do to what i need? thanks!

Comment: "there are a lot of packages that i need" - that's exactly why you should use a general purpose distribution for this, rather than kali.

Comment: @cas in kali there are lot of packages that i need, that why i use kali. but please leave it and try to answer on what i need

Comment: there is **nothing** in kali that isn't also available for other distributions.  But there is a vast array of software in other distros that isn't available packaged for kali.  You are using the wrong distro for the job you want to do.  Kali is suitable for pen-testing, it is not suitable for any other use.  I have given you the best answer you can get on this question: Use Another Distro.   (And, BTW, installing Kali on a VM which doesn't even have any network access?  WTF?  that's severely misguided at best, completely misses the entire point of Kali).

Comment: @cas   ok , but... is there any option to develop small c# on kali? i try apt-get install monodevelop and i get invalid operation

Answer (score 1):

Since the question start with "The VM doesn't have Internet connection" I'd suggest to solve the problem by providing Internet access to the VM.

The easy solution might be [setting the VirtualBox Network option](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) to: Bridge or NAT which will enable the Kali-VM Internet access ([instruction example](https://www.linuxbabe.com/virtualbox/a-pretty-good-introduction-to-virtualbox-bridged-networking-mode)).

Another option is to attach *USB-WIFI dongle* to the VM.

Once the Kali VM will be connected to the Internet, follow the regular install instructions.

Comment: my vm is under proxi withour option to download anything

Comment: Why a kali VM should be behind a proxy? Why can't you download anything to the VM? do you have physical access to the machine running the VM (can you attach USB-WIFI dongle to the VM)?

Comment: on my collage that is the situation. i ca'n't attach usb as wifi.   is there any option to solve my problem? thank